# A very hard Neo4j question to mimic the double for loop?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have three kinds of nodes: `me`(one node), `myFriend`, `friendOfFriend`, and I want to:

1. Create relation between `me` and `myFriend` where we have two attributes the same value.
2. Create relation between `friend` and `friendOfFriend` where they have two attributes the same value, but `friendOfFriend` should exclude `me`.
3. Create relation between `me` and `friendOfFriend` where we have two attributes the same value, but `friendOfFriend` should exclude `friend`.

I'm new to neo4j and I found the documentation very hard to read and provide very little info./example about how to use basic tools, instead it verbose on advertise "Yes, we are good please funding us". Anyway, let's see the pseudocode version of my requirements:

```
match (me) where me.a1="Rain"

for i in range(all_nodes):
    CONSTANT_ME = [me.a2, me.a3]  #  <------- How to #1
    if i.a2 in CONSTANT_ME:
        # create friend relationship between me and i.

for i in range(friend):
    CONSTANT_FRIEND = [friend.a2, friend.a3]
    for j in range(friend):
        if j.a2 in CONSTANT_FRIEND
        AND j.a3 in CONSTANT_FRIEND:
            # create FF relationship between node i and j
```

I want to write the above in `Neo4j`'s Cypher langauge, what I've tried is:

```
MATCH (me:Classmate), (c:Classmate)
WHERE ID(me) < ID(c)
AND me.a1="Rain" AND c.a1<>"Rain"
AND ANY(x in [me.a2, me.a3] WHERE x in [c.a2, c.a3])
CREATE (me)-[:friend]->(c);

MATCH (c1:Classmate), (c2:Classmate)
WHERE ID(c1) < ID(c2)
AND c1.a1<>"Rain" AND c2.a1<>"Rain"
AND ANY(x in [c1.a2, c1.a3] WHERE x in [c2.a2, c2.a3])
CREATE (c1)-[:friendOfFriend]->(c2);

MATCH (me:Classmate), (c2:Classmate)
WHERE ID(me) < ID(c2)
AND c1.a1="Rain" AND c2.a1<>"Rain"
AND ANY(x in [me.a2, me.a3] WHERE x in [c2.a2, c2.a3])
CREATE (me)-[:meFF]->(c2);
```

As you can see this is very verbose and I cannot prevent that:

- Repeat code is bad: `[me.a2, me.a3]` is declared twice.
- I cannot prevent creating a `[:meFF]` to a node which already has been `[:friend]` with `me`.

Finally, does any one recommend some good tutorial on Neo4j which teaches the basic comprising how to solve problems like this one I encountered?

Comment: Well, nothing in your queries shows any unique lookup of the `me` node. Is it really meant to specify a single specific individual with a local graph from it, or is this meant to be a graph-wide query to consider :friend relationships between all :Classmate nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn to think differently. Graphs change your world view!

Me, my friend and friend of my friend are all Persons. Thus, you want one node label and 3 nodes linked together. Try this

```
create (p1:Person{name:'Me'})
create (p2:Person{name:'My Friend'})
create (p3:Person{name:'Friend of my Friend'})
merge (p1)-[r1:friend]-(p2)
merge (p2)-[r2:friend]-(p3)
```

Then

```
match p=(a:Person{name:'Me'})-[r:friend*0..5]->(b:Person) return p
```